# How to block a URL in TOR browser?

Tags: windows, blocking, tor

I am trying to use [Block Site](https://add0n.com/block-site.html) extension to block access to some URLs in TOR browser in Windows 7. This extension works: it blocks the sites I want to be blocked. However a user can easily disable or remove the extension from the browser. I tried to prevent disabling or removing this extension in TOR browser. I found the following recommendation in Block Site FAQs.

> How can I prevent this extension from being removed or disabled from the Firefox browser?
>
> Create a `policies.json` file with the following content. This file sits
>   into a directory called `distribution` within the Firefox installation
>   directory. You can use it to control how users have access to the
>   browser features. For more info visit
>   [github.com/mozilla/policy-templates](http://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates)
>
> ```
> {   "policies": {
>     "Extensions": {
>       "Locked":  ["{54e2eb33-18eb-46ad-a4e4-1329c29f6e17}"]
>     }   } }
> ```

I tried, but creating `policies.json` had no effect: Block Site extension still could be removed or disabled. I tried the following more simple commands in `policies.json`, still no effect:

```
{
 "policies": {
   "BlockAboutAddons": true
 }
}
```

Another drawback of using Block Site extension is that it compromises the anonymity in TOR browser.

Is there a better way to block URLs in TOR?

Answer (score 0):

I installed a trial version of [FocusMe](https://focusme.com/), it seems to do what I need and it seems to be very promising.